# Error installing MoveIt 2 from source on Ubuntu 20.04 VM

Tags: cmake, ros2, moveit

I'm trying to get involved in open source and also am quite interested in robotics, so I thought about contributing to MoveIt 2. As a first step, I'm installing MoveIt 2 from source on my Ubuntu 20.04 VM in VirtualBox.

I've run through all the instructions here: [https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/source/#:~:text=colcon%20build%20%2D%2Devent%2Dhandlers%20desktop_notification%2D%20status%2D%20%2D%2Dcmake%2Dargs%20%2DDCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%3DRelease](https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/source/#:%7E:text=colcon%20build%20%2D%2Devent%2Dhandlers%20desktop_notification%2D%20status%2D%20%2D%2Dcmake%2Dargs%20%2DDCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%3DRelease)

However, the build is failing on the highlighted part. The error message is as follows:

```
Starting >>> geometric_shapes
--- stderr: geometric_shapes
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findeigen3_cmake_module.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "eigen3_cmake_module", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "eigen3_cmake_module" with any of the following names:

    eigen3_cmake_moduleConfig.cmake
    eigen3_cmake_module-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "eigen3_cmake_module" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "eigen3_cmake_module_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "eigen3_cmake_module" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.


---
Failed   <<< geometric_shapes [1.20s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.46s]
  1 package failed: geometric_shapes
  1 package had stderr output: geometric_shapes
  33 packages not processed
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have the eigen cmake module installed via apt?

Comment: @BTables when I issue `apt list --installed | grep eigen` I can see this: `libeigen3-dev/focal,focal,now 3.3.7-2 all [installed]`. Not sure if this is the same module?

Comment: To ensure the question is useful even in the link is no longer available, it would be helpful to quote the steps that you tried which resulted in the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install ROS2 before building Move It 2. After installing the ROS2 binaries, the error doesn't occur.